# Automated Testing issue

Tags: java, selenium, maven, appium, saucelabs

Very new to Automated Testing using Selenium and Appium.
The entire setup was done by some vendor long back. 
Now i ran my test and the first test itself failed and I get the below error.

[image]

The error is as shown below
But I have my api key as shown below.

[image]

error:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 12.048 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] runner.RunWebScenario.runScenario["Login Mode - General and Appointment Notifications Retrieval @Device:Mobile", "HAGo-NC"](1)  Time elapsed: 2.437 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
No Sauce Connect tunnel found for identifier 'act-rdc'
Command duration or timeout: 1.81 seconds
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
No Sauce Connect tunnel found for identifier 'act-rdc'
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'pd2macbook1.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c5a:9e1a:d4fb:a12a%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.4', java.version: '13.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   RunWebScenario>AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario:22 » WebDriver No Sauce...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  56.735 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-11T10:37:19+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project ha-go-test-plan: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/raksha/auto/notif-center-act/ha-go-test-plan/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

What is causing this issue? 
Automated testing is very confusing. Really need some guidance here!!

Is the issue "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project ha-go-test-plan: There are test failures." 
or 
"No sauce connect tunnel......."??

If any further test data or screenshots are needed please comment and I will provide.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that your test requested a tunnel with the identifier "act-rdc" but it couldn't find one.

There's a few reasons that might be:

1. You haven't manually started a tunnel with that identifier
2. Your tooling usually starts tunnels but is failing to do so in your local environment
3. You have started a tunnel, but it's not accessible to the user running the tests

I'm *guessing* your GitLab environment probably brings the tunnel up for you, or has one constantly running, and in Eclipse you're running a different setup.

Answer (score 0):

Some assertion statement failed in your test (Line 22 in AbstractTestNGCucumberTests):

```
RunWebScenario>AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario:22
```

Obviously you have the parameterized test

```
runner.RunWebScenario.runScenario["Login Mode - General and Appointment Notifications Retrieval @Device:Mobile", "HAGo-NC"](1)
```

with two parameters:

1. "Login Mode - General and Appointment Notifications Retrieval @Device:Mobile"
2. "HAGo-NC"

It's the first combination of parameters (1) which failed.

Comment: strangely the tests run successfully when we run it our pipeline in gitlab. Only when we try to run it in eclipse using SuaceLab tunnel we are facing this issue. "No Sauce Connect tunnel found for identifier 'act-rdc'" fails with this error. Not able to figure out is it Sauce tunnel issue or something wrong with one of the maven plugins/files.

Comment: This log is not printed by the Maven, either the plugins. You should start around the Selenium, configuration and your test. Because seems to be related to the tunnel issue as you said. A kind of network issue.

Comment: A good point from Dylan. I am also convinced that this has to do with a connectivity to the tunnel or an environment configuration.